# Best practices: Separate or single databases?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture

i'm so confuse now to design good architecture for financial transactional system.
For example : 
i have some tables :

1. **MSMembers** (for provide member profile and username password of member)
2. **TRTransactions** (table record all transaction that comes from other host, such as member's host)
3. **MSFees** (list for tiering fee related with number of the transaction)

In my opinion, i think i can :

1. Separated the database for transactional and master data. For example, 
   **DBMaster** : MSMembers, MSFees; 
   **DBTransaction** : TRTransactions
   So my application (my TransactionService not the web), must connect to multiple database, is it effective if my service connect to multiple database?
2. Or, same with point 1, but i create MSMembers and MSFees in the DBTransaction, so TransacionService doesn't need connect to multiple database.

Please some advise for this case.

Thanks before. :)

Comment: What sort of financial transactions are you looking at?   anyway I believe there is an answer to part of your question so would recommend against closing while I write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to go with separate databases unless you are on MySQL (and in which case `database` means `schema` in other databases).  Additionally it isn't clear why you would separate these into different schemas in the first place.  There is really nothing to gain from this unless you want effectively to use different schemata to manage different sides of your application.

So keep everything in one database.  Much easier that way, and you can enforce real database constraints (referential integrity etc) between the parts.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. Actually, i think that i want separated because, 1 database server that consist of many tables that use by transaction, and 1 database server to manage for web content or manage like fee transaction, customer data, user management, etc. For your information, i use postgresql. :)

Comment: There is a saying "premature optimization is the root of all evil."  PostgreSQL scales up (and now out) very, very well.  and given that financial transaction tables are not only likely to be the largest in your database but are usually append only (thus handle balance points you can roll forward from well), there is no reason to use multiple databases.  FWIW I work with dbs of up to 11TB handling around two million db write transactions a day.....